# Do women have to tolerate abuse from their husbands?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, hadith-interpretation, women, husband-wife

So, I saw this [Fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/88353/what-is-the-reward-for-spouses-treating-one-another-kindly) on islamqa and it quoted a Hadith. This part of the Hadith says:

> Shall I not tell you about your women in Paradise?” We said: Yes, O Messenger of Allah. He said: “The loving and fertile one who, if she gets angry or is mistreated or her husband gets angry says, ‘Here is my hand in your hand, I shall not sleep until you are pleased.’”

As far as the authenticity of the Hadith goes, the article says:

> It was also narrated from a number of other Sahabah, hence it was classed as hasan by al-Albani in al-Silsilah al-Saheehah (3380) and in Saheeh al-Targheeb (1942).

Does this mean that women have to tolerate mistreatment and abuse from their husbands? And what if a woman is not fertile? Isn’t she deserving of Paradise because Allah has made the fertile women superior?

Comment: You must first ask "Can men mistreat or abuse his wife in islam?". And i think [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/CQOGOBzhEiQ/) instagram post explain it well (There's a doubtful hadith in slide 8 though). and about do women have to tolerate abuse, i don't know if it's better to do so or not but women can declare a [khula](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/26247/khula-definition-and-how-it-is-done) if she wanted to. About the fertile one, i don't know. and Allah knows best.

Comment: @valikaze125 I know that it’s not allowed for men to abuse their wives, but my question is that if in case they do, then should women tolerate the abuse?

Comment: @Ma148 It's only considered abuse in Islam when a man does more than screaming at or lightly hitting his wife. If he goes off in a tyrant mode and ACTUALLY ABUSES his wife then he is the one guilty and the wife should take khula but the ones that still tolerate are the most superior women in paradise.

A wife in Islam is not exactly equal to her husband she is her servant, and the husband is her master. That is also the reason that men in Islam are allowed to have 4 wives at one time while women aren't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "must" as you say, but in Islam it is an aspect of encouraging patience, advice and suggestion. This is because if a man or a woman is not patient and retaliates or divorces his wife, the center of that family will fall apart and we have narrations that divorce is the most hated thing in Islam. And marriage and family formation is the most popular and valuable building in Islam. That is why many men and women are encouraged to be patient in the face of their spouse's immorality. So that this family center does not fall apart.

In some narrations, it is stated that the torment of the grave has been removed from three groups of women. Some of them are those who are patient with their husbands' immorality. At the end of this hadith, it is stated that God gives the reward of a thousand martyrs to each of these three groups of women for their patience, and for each of them, the reward of one year of worship is written in their deeds.
It is mentioned in another hadith of the Holy Prophet (PBUH). Every man who shows patience and forbearance over his wife's immorality, God will reward the man who gave him to David - or Ayub (peace be upon him) for enduring disasters. And if a woman bears the immorality of her husband and is patient, God will provide her with the reward that she has given to Mr. Asia, one of the top four women in Paradise.
On the other hand, there are many hadiths that forbid men from committing immorality with their wives and family members and frighten them of immoral punishment. As far as it is stated in the hadith: Any woman or man who annoys his wife with his immorality, God does not accept their prayers and other acts of worship and good deeds, even if he has always been in worship.